# ELBのアクセスログをUTCからJSTに変更したい。

Tags: aws, amazon-elb

現在、ELBからアクセスログをs3に保存する仕組みを利用しているのですが、
現在ELBからログを収集しているのですが、標準ではUTCで出力されてしまいます。
公式のドキュメントにはISO 8601のフォーマットで出力されるとのみ書かれてあり
詳細は書かれていませんでした。

- Monitor Your Load Balancer Using Elastic Load Balancing Access Logs
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-log-collection.html

そこで質問なのですがJST(UTC+9)のように
出力してくれるような設定はありますでしょうか。

```
2016-04-28T03:15:34.003052Z
```

なければ、プログラムでJSTに変更するロジックを入れようと考えています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

> そこで質問なのですがJST(UTC+9)のように
>   出力してくれるような設定はありますでしょうか。

APIを見てもそういったパラメータはないので存在しないと思います。